# How to apply a function to only one row

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a dateset like:

```
a    b     c
1    x1    c1
2    x2    c2    
3    x3    c3
```

and I want to apply a function f only to the column b.

I did something like :

```
d2 = d['b'].apply(f)
```

But I have result like

```
a    b 
1    xt
2    xt    
3    xt
```

And I want the column c, a result like :

```
a    b     c
1    xt    c1
2    xt    c2    
3    xt    c3
```

How can I do that without merge with the first dataset ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you try don't use `apply`, because it is slower, better is use `pandas` API functions:

e.g. if need replace column to new constant values:

```
df['b'] = 'xt'
print (df)
   a   b   c
0  1  xt  c1
1  2  xt  c2
2  3  xt  c3
```

But if `apply` is necessary:

```
def f(x):
    return 'xt'

df['b'] = df.b.apply(f)
print (df)
   a   b   c
0  1  xt  c1
1  2  xt  c2
2  3  xt  c3
```

If you need new `DataFrame`, first use [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
d = df.copy()

def f(x):
    return 'xt'

d['b'] = d.b.apply(f)
print (d)
   a   b   c
0  1  xt  c1
1  2  xt  c2
2  3  xt  c3
```